# How to add custom CSS to an article in Joomla 1.5.20?

Tags: html, css, joomla, joomla1.5

How to add custom CSS to an article in Joomla 1.5.20?

I have installed JUMI, but see no effect of it in article editor.

How to use it?

I have a bunch of CSS styles to apply.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I would love to rant on about how you should upgrade to Joomla 2.5 or 3.2, I won't but please at least upgrade to Joomla 1.5.26 which is the latest version of the 1.5 series.

To add custom CSS to your article, simply download and install a plugin called [Sourcerer](http://download.nonumber.nl/?ext=sourcerer&v=3.3.0). This plugin allows you to add custom code to any article. Once installed, open your article in the Article Manager and you can use the following for custom CSS:

```
{source}
<style>
    #element {
         //code goes here
    }   
</style>
{/source}
```

This extensions can also be used for Javascript/jQuery and PHP. I have used this extension on multiple website and it simply just does the job.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Back when I used joomla 1.5, which has hit end of life and is recommended to upgrade to joomla 2,5 or higher. I used Flexi Custom Code. I would also create a module position in the head of my template that would allow me to stick the custom code into.

If Jumi Works like flexi did, then you just have to add a a pair of  tags around your css and publish it to a specific position.

[EDIT]
When You add the CSS you add the Css code you create a new module, and publish the module to a position in the template that is being displayed.
[/EDIT]

That is How I used to do it.

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry can't imagine what are you saying. I can't edit any tags. I can edit article in WYSIWYG, there are no tags. Also I can press `Edit Code` button and have some code opened in separate window. But this window "eats" any code I enter there. Where to put something you are saying about?

Comment: Sorry about that. It was a brain fart. I just edited it. Hope that is a little more clear

Comment: I am afraid I need step-by-step instructions. I have no idea, what are "templates" and "positions". I think I have no such things in my joomla (I have only web access... may be this is about ftp access... but if I had ftp access, I would be able to hardcode any css anywhere and no question arose)

Comment: THis is all done in the administrator portion of joomla. The template is the code that tells joomla how to display content. It is accessed through the template manager.

Comment: Erm.. why on earth would you create a new module position to simply add custom CSS to an article?

Comment: Without using the JCE editor joomla strips out the style code.